# SQL Query retrieving info from 3 tables which are in relationship

Tags: mysql, key, foreign-key-relationship

I even don't know how to title my problem or what to search to solve it so please don't mind me if I don't describe it properly.

I have 3 tables:

Patient(**id**, name, ....)

Examination(**id**, date, patient_id*, notes)

Diagnoses(**id**, diagnose)

ExaminationDijagnose(**id**, diagnose_id*, examination_id*)

So I want to make a query where is only one input parameter and that is ExaminationID (Primary Key). The result will be one row with columns

(examination_id, date, name, diagnoses(array), notes).

The diagnoses column will be an array based on a examination_id foreign key.

So like this if examination id is 10
Diagnose:
1 - Flu
2 - High temperature

ExaminationDijagnose will be
1 , 1 , 10
1 , 2 , 10

I need output to look like this
1(ExaminationID), date, patient_name(patient_id*), Array(Flu, High Temperature), notes)

That array is concatination, so diagnose period diagnose. "Flu, High Temperature, Fracture etc...

Sorry again if I described it badly.
Thanks

Comment: How are you expecting to get an array in `diagnoses(array)` when the result will be one row only?

Comment: You need to use "JOIN". You use the join and set the relationship.

SELECT person.* FROM Examination
JOIN Patient ON Examination.patient_id = Patient.patient_id
JOIN XXXX on ....

Comment: @dat3450 I think I explained it more clearly now.

Comment: So the array of diagnoses will actually be a string with a comma `,` separating the items. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query would look something like the following (updated to include the array of diagnoses):

```
SELECT examination_id, date, name, GROUP_CONCAT(diagnose), notes
FROM Patient
INNER JOIN Examination ON Examination.patient_id = Patient.id
INNER JOIN ExaminationDiagnose ON ExaminationDiagnose.examination_id = Examination.id
INNER JOIN Diagnoses ON Diagnoses.id = ExaminationDiagnose.diagnose_id
WHERE Examination.id = ?
```

Comment: You saved me a lot times searching for a solution. The key was GROUP CONCAT.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` with `GROUP_CONCAT` function to get the array of diagnoses, e.g.:

```
SELECT e.id, e.date, p.id, p.name, notes, GROUP_CONCAT(d.diagnose)
FROM examination e JOIN ExaminationDiagnose ed ON e.id = ed.examination_id
JOIN patient p ON e.patient_id = p.id
JOIN diagnose d ON ed.diagnose_id = d.id
WHERE e.id = ?
GROUP BY e.id, e.date, p.id, p.name, notes;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html MySQL doesn't support Array but you can use JSON Array if required.

If you want the list of Diagnose to be part of your select query regardless of type, the following query will get you the comma (,) separated list of diagnoses. Which you can later tansform to any format you want by spliting the string by comma (,).

```
SELECT examination.id, examination.date, patient.name, group_concat(diagnoses.diagnose) as diagonses, examination.notes
FROM ExaminationDijagnose ed 
JOIN Examination examination on examination.id = ed.examination_id 
JOIN Patient patient on patient.id = examination.patient_id 
JOIN Diagnoses diagnoses on diagnoses.id = ed.diagnoses_id
GROUP BY examination.id, examination.date, patient.name, examination.notes
```